# java.lang.StackOverflowError on pyspark join

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to do join of two same dataset (10gb each) and facing the below issue. Note: If i use small dataset everything is working fine. Any help on this issue??
Dataset Info: It has around 701 columns,
Spark Config: Driver memory:2Gb, Driver cores: 2,Executor memory: 19gb, Executor Cores: 5, num of Executors: 4

```
df1=spark.read.format("csv").option("header",True).option("inferSchema",True).load(input_path)
df2=spark.read.format("csv").option("header",True).option("inferSchema",True).load(input_path)
outputDf=join(df1,df2) # join function
print(outputDf.count())
```

Logs:

```
2022-06-27T15:50:27.799360066Z : java.lang.StackOverflowError
2022-06-27T15:50:27.799431009Z  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:438)
2022-06-27T15:50:27.799438757Z  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:244)
2022-06-27T15:50:27.799443294Z  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:406)
2022-06-27T15:50:27.799447490Z  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:359)
```

Comment: could this be due to a cartesian join? check the job(s) DAGs on spark UI to see the plan

Comment: is this `join` function your custom function?  (afaik, spark's join syntax is `df1.join(df2)`)

Comment: @Emma it is spark join only

Comment: @samkart It is highly possible , it can cartesian join. Irrespective of joins, what would be the root cause for this problem?

Comment: based on the code provided, i can't think of anything other than a cross join. reiterating, check the spark UI for the process DAGs which will tell you what spark is trying to do

Comment: @samkart In spark UI during join, I am not able to see any stage or task, it is completely stuck and the driver throwed above error.

Comment: do you really want a cross join? if not, you should explicitly provide join keys in the join condition

Comment: @samkart Yes i need the cross join of the dataframes